# Matrix with ones on the diagonal and other constant on non diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra

I have  $ n \times n $ real matrix $A$ with 1 on the diagonal and a constant $ c \ne 1 $ on non diagonal entries. I want to prove the matrix is invertible or come with a counter example. I think it is true and tried many examples but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Edit: I require that $ c \ne -1 $ as well

Edit : $ 0<c<1 $

In this case I think $A$ is invertible : define $c=cos^2\alpha $ and have $ A=sin^2\alpha I_n+cos^2\alpha J_n $ where $J_n$ is the all one matrix. $\; sin^2\alpha I_n $ is positive definite and $cos^2\alpha J_n $ is PSD (leading principle minors are non negative). Their sum must be positive definite so $A$ is positive definite and therefore invertible.

Is this a valid proposition ?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are talking about a particular kind of circulant matrix. The determinant of a circulant matrix is explicitly known, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). Also note that the rank is given by $n$ minus the degree of the gcd of the circulant polynomial (in this case that polynomial is $1+cx+cx^2+...+cx^{n-1}$) with $x^n-1$, and therefore calculating this gcd is sufficient for seeing if the rank is full or not, and if the matrix is invertible or not.

Comment: I'll modify the question to make c != -1 as well

Comment: A special case of this is [Is a matrix with 1
s in the diagonal and off-diagonal entries with absolute value less than 1
invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/300028/139123) The answer there is also "no."

Comment: Note that answers to the question I just linked to show that not only $c\neq 1$ is insufficient, but even adding the condition $c\neq -1$ is insufficient for $n \geq 3.$

Comment: I am curious what examples you tried.  In the $3\times 3$ case you can easily explicitly compute the determinant as a function of $c$ to find a counterexample.

Comment: Look at my updated question with $ 0 < c < 1 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The all-1's matrix $J$ of rank $1$ has eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ by the rank nullity theorem, and $n$ with multiplicity $1$ (the all-1's vector is an eigenvector).

Your matrix is $cJ+(1-c)I$. Its eigenvalues, then, are $(1-c)$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $cn+(1-c)$ with multiplicity $1$.

Your matrix is non-singular provided these eigenvalues are non-zero.